# How to return all the results in search:search API?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using `search:search` API and came across a scenario in which I want all the docs returned.

I know it will impact the performance but I can bear this as I know there won't be more than 30-50 docs.

I can set the max **threshold** value which is **50**, but just want to know is there way to return all the results.

If in future the count increases I don't need to change the threshold value.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a large pageLength, something like `999` or even bigger.

I'd go for something smaller though, and put in logic that checks whether total count exceeds pageLength, and print a notification if that occurs..

HTH!

Comment: One footnote on Geert's good guidance -- if you are sending a request from the client, the best practice is to page over the result set, getting perhaps 100 documents in each request.