# How can I get complete page-length result through search:search in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using search:search to get all the docs, return as a result at a time instead of set $page-length=1000. Because if there will be more data from the UI than how can I set $page-length each time and how can I return all the results.

Is there any way to set $page-length=[complete result]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226469/how-to-return-all-the-results-in-searchsearch-api

Comment: Thanks, Can I set page length any bigger number (say 99999) is it a valid way? Please suggest!

Comment: You could. It is an xs:unsignedLong. That won't help much though. A better approach would be to use pageLength 100, and page through till you got all. You can use `start` to get subsequent pages..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return all the results in search:search API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226469/how-to-return-all-the-results-in-searchsearch-api)